# Mass remove a number of tags from a number of posts

Tags: tags

i am having a wallpapers site. I was having lots of posts with no tags and i tried some plugins to auto add tags like simple tags where you need to set some tags and it will auto use those tags for posts, then i used auto tag posts option and it added all the 50-60 tags to a number of individual posts,Means it added 50-60 tags to each of the posts in 500 posts. Its very time consuming now for me to edit each post and removing unwanted tags. Is there any way so that i can remove those 50-60 tags via a MySQL query? Any way either a plugin or a mysql query can do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To change tags on a mass of posts can you use the default mass edit mode of WordPress. This more secure as a sql-statement.
If you are on the edit post page, there you see all posts. Open the options on right top and edit a number of posts, there you will edit, maybe 500.

[image]

After this changes switch to the mass edit mode. Active all posts with the checkbox and use `Edit` in the `Bulk Mode`. Also a screenshot.

[image]

Now you get a textarea with all tags, there are in all posts and you can remove the tags.

A alternative is the plugin [Search Replace](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/), that can change tags to each post via sql statement, but is more directly on the database and not secure.

Comment: No that won't help in removing tags from all the selected posts. When i selected the posts with 50-60 tags and tried mass editing, it haven't shown me the tags in the tags box, it was empty for me. Please suggest another way...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WordPress › Bulk Move « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-move/) It works in a different way than the WP bulk edit mode and might be useful.

> Bulk Move is a WordPress Plugin which can be used to move posts in
>   bulk from one category or tag to another. This Plugin can also be used
>   to remove posts from a certain category or tag.